# Why does Pydantic accept an empty string as a UUID

Tags: python, fastapi, uuid, pydantic

I have a Fast Api with Pydantic. Using BaseModel, i have a field that needs to be a UUID:
`id: UUID`. However when i send in an empty string it allows it, why is that?

Answer (score 2):

It's not pydantic, pydantic raises an error just fine.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from uuid import UUID

class Model(BaseModel):
    id: UUID


Model(id='')
```

Raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 341, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Model
id
  value is not a valid uuid (type=type_error.uuid)
```

Answer (score -1):

To enforce it, you can use the constr field type from Pydantic and apply a regex for validation.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, constr, validator
import uuid

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    id: constr(regex=r'^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}$')

    @validator('id')
    def validate_uuid(cls, value):
        uuid.UUID(value)
        return value
```

Comment: Pydantic does perform this validation: https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/types/#standard-library-types:~:text=strict%20path%20types-,uuid.UUID,-strings%20and%20bytes

Comment: And has since [v0.5.0](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/changelog/#v050-2017-10-23) ... 2017